# Tabulate\Ods.ExcelXP - Use tagattr on var and style on class

Tags: sas, sas-ods

So here, I am losing the TagAttr on the highlighted "All" row.  What I want is the Total row to be highlighted and to also maintain the TagAttr on the output.

```
ods tagsets.excelxp
file= "c:\Sheet1.xml"

proc tabulate data=sashelp.class missing;
class sex age;
var height;
table (sex='' all='Total')*
(age=''
all={label='Total NCO' s={background=yellow font_weight=bold}} *{s={font_weight=bold background=yellow }}),
(height='Height'*mean=' ' *[s=[tagattr='#,##0;[Red](#,##0);"-"']]
height='%height'*pctsum=''*[s=[tagattr='0.00%;[Red]0.00%;"-";"-"']])

/ box=_page_ style_precedence=row;
run;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

Comment: I tried to figure this out and couldn't in my limited time right now.  I think the solution is some combination of using `style=<parent>` and the `keyword` statement, but I can't get it to work.  If you can't and don't get better help here, I would post on communities.sas.com under ODS section and see if Cynthia has a solution - she's very good at these sorts of things.  (I was using http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/stylesinprocs.pdf for example to see if I could figure the solution out, such as around page 17-18.)

Comment: One thing is that this may be a bit easier if you use template styles - you might be able to get it to use the right style if you make different  styles in PROC TEMPLATE for the different things you are trying to do (including a combined style that contains the yellow and the tagattr).

Comment: Thanks Joe.  Have been talking with Cynthia for a day, still no answers.

Comment: Ah.  Honestly if Cynthia doesn't know, I suspect nobody does outside of the developer(s), and you should open a ticket with sas support.

Comment: Ha.  If Cynthia doesn't know AND I don't know, then it's really a puzzle.